# Replacing values in a matrix by specified values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, replace

I have a three dimensional array of simulated data (dimensions are *10000*-by-*16*-by-*312* or #trials by TimeSeries by horizons). I would like to replace values above / below a pre-specified threshold with the threshold values. I have calculated the threshold values for each individual time series in `MinAcceptableVal(:,i)` and `MaxAcceptableVal(:,i)`. When I run the code I do not receive an error message, but the values above the threshold are not cut off.

```
for i=1:nIndices
    simulatedReturnsEVT1(simulatedReturnsEVT1(:,i,:)<MinAcceptableVal(:,i))=MinAcceptableVal(:,i); 
    simulatedReturnsEVT1(simulatedReturnsEVT1(:,i,:)>MaxAcceptableVal(:,i))=MaxAcceptableVal(:,i); 
end
```

I have tried to use the code in a different form (see below) before and it worked perfectly. Matlab seems to be having problems with me introducing different cutoff levels for the different time series variables (`i`).

```
simulatedReturnsEVT1(simulatedReturnsEVT1<-1)=-1; 
simulatedReturnsEVT1(simulatedReturnsEVT1>1)=1;
```

I would be very happy about any Hints!

Comment: What are the dimensions of `MinAcceptableVal`?

Comment: Hi Dan, the dimensions of MinAcceptableVal and MaxAcceptableVal are (1,16)

Comment: pick a value for `i` (I suggest `1`) and see what `simulatedReturnsEVT1(:,i,:)<MinAcceptableVal(:,i)` actually produces. Then you'll see that your error is trying to use a slice of a 3D matrix (i.e. *10000*-by-*1*-by-*312*) as a linear index to your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
for i=1:nIndices
    slice = simulatedReturnsEVT1(:,i,:);
    slice(slice < MinAcceptableVal(i))=MinAcceptableVal(:,i);
    slice(slice > MaxAcceptableVal(i))=MaxAcceptableVal(:,i);
    simulatedReturnsEVT1(:,i,:) = slice;        
end
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks, your solutions works perfectly :-). Have a great day!